# Address book Phone number (+45) prefix causing crash!

Tags: iphone, crash, addressbook, prefix

I am having trouble getting phone numbers from the iPhone Addressbook.

There is no problem when the number do not contain a country code prefix like +45, but if it does, my app crashes...

Is this a known issue? I haven't been able to find anything about it...

Thanks

EDIT:

I get phonenumber like this:

```
    -(void)getContact 
    {

        ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *pp = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
        pp.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty]];
        pp.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:pp animated:YES];
        [pp release];


    }

    - (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {
        // assigning control back to the main controller
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
        return YES;
    }

-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {

            ABMultiValueRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person,property);
            saveString = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneProperty,identifier);
            saveString = [saveString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
            nummerTextField.text = saveString;
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your code?  And where in it does the crash happen?

Comment: Perhaps someone at Apple dislikes the Danish ;) Seems somewhat unlikely though.

Comment: :-) The crash happens at the saveString = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneProperty,identifier); but only if the number has a prefix like +45...

Comment: The app freezes when i touch a phonenumber with a +xx prefix... Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you retrieving your Address book object, and once it is retrieved how do you process it to fetch the number from it.I am using the below shown code to do the same what you have mentioned and it fetches the numbers accurately.

```
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(appDelegate.addressBook, contactId);

ABMultiValueRef multiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

NSArray *allNumbers = (NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(multiValue);
NSMutableDictionary *filteredNumbers = [NSMutableDictionary new];

if([allNumbers count] > 0) {
    for(int contactIndex = 0; contactIndex < [allNumbers count]; contactIndex++) {
        NSString *contactValue = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multiValue, contactIndex);
        if(!([contactValue isEqualToString:@"_$!<WorkFAX>!$_"] || [contactValue isEqualToString:@"_$!<HomeFAX>!$_"] || [contactValue isEqualToString:@"_$!<Pager>!$_"])) {

            if([[contactValue substringWithRange:contactLabelCharacterCustom] isEqualToString:@"_$"])
                typeOfContact = [contactValue substringWithRange:contactLabelCharacter];
            else
                typeOfContact = [contactValue substringWithRange:(NSRange){0,1}];
            NSString *value = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, contactIndex);
            [filteredNumbers setValue:typeOfContact forKey:value];
            [value release];
            value = nil;
        }
        [contactValue release];
        contactValue = nil;
    }
}
```

Im sure it will help you.

Cheers

Comment: Just tried it out... I am accessing the numbers by the user choosing witch number/email ect. he/she wants. Could not get your example to work :( Maybe I will try it again later if all else fails ;)

Comment: Arh... There appears to be a new problem... If there is more than 1 phonenumber, regardless of which one I pick, the second one is selected... How can I fix that? Anyone??

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem. Hope someone finds it helpful.

```
ABMultiValueRef multiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);

        NSString *number = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(multiValue, identifier));

// Error was here: NSString *value = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiValue, contactIndex);

        //Copy the number etc before cleaning everything up

        saveString = number;
        saveString = [saveString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        nummerTextField.text = saveString;

        [number release];
        CFRelease(multiValue);
```