# App crashes when contact number that contains a "+" is selected

Tags: objective-c, abpersonviewcontroller

I have an iPhone app. The user can select a contact. Upon selection another view is opened where the user has to select a phone number.

This works great. However when the phone number contains country code like this `+49 ...` the app crashes.

```
-(BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{
    ABMutableMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
    CFStringRef phone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, identifier);

    ///....some code

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [personViewController.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return NO;
}
```

It stops at this line

```
CFStringRef phone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, identifier);
```

but there is no error output in the log. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Address book Phone number (+45) prefix causing crash!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712071/address-book-phone-number-45-prefix-causing-crash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you insert that "+" but you should try to get it replaced by something it can work with.

```
[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"00"];
```

If it doesn't help try to follow this link:
[Address book Phone number (+45) prefix causing crash!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712071/address-book-phone-number-45-prefix-causing-crash)